# Get unique values in a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list made up of arrays. All have shape (2,).

Minimum example: `mylist = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]`

I would like to get a unique list, e.g.
`[np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]`

or perhaps even better, a dict with counts, e.g. `{np.array([1,2]) : 2, np.array([3,4]) : 1}`

So far I tried `list(set(mylist))`, but the error is `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the best option is to use `np.unique` method with custom parameters

`u, idx, counts = np.unique(X, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)`

Then, according to [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

- `u` is an array of unique arrays
- `idx` is the indices of the `X` that give the unique values
- `counts` is the number of times each unique item appears in `X`

If you need a dictionary, you can't store `hashable` values in its keys, so you might like to store them as tuples like in @yatu's answer or like this:

`dict(zip([tuple(n) for n in u], counts))`

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicates, NumPy arrays aren't hashable. You can turn them to tuples, which *are hashable* and build a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the result:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(map(tuple,mylist))
# Counter({(1, 2): 2, (3, 4): 1})
```

If you wanted a list of unique tuples, you could construct a `set`:

```
set(map(tuple,mylist))
# {(1, 2), (3, 4)}
```

Comment: This answer is also good, but I accepted another one as that's what I decided to use in the end.

Comment: If you have a list of equally shaped arrays, do construct an array from it, so that you can leverage numpy's functions. `np.array(mylist)`, and hence have a much better performance. Since you posted a list in the question, I assumed the inner arrays could be different in shape @cddt

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. You are correct, I should have converted the list to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Pure numpy approach:

```
numpy.unique(mylist, axis=0)
```

which produces a 2d array with your unique arrays in rows:

```
numpy.array([
 [1 2],
 [3 4]])
```

Works if all your arrays have same length (like in your example).
This solution can be useful depending on what you do earlier in your code: perhaps you would not need to get into plain Python at all, but stick to numpy instead, which should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]
np.unique(mylist, axis=0)
```

This gives out list of uniques arrays.

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Source: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#how-to-get-unique-items-and-counts

Comment: You might want to mention that this will internally construct a 2d array from the list, which will fail if one of inner arrays has a different length